# How to make an excel (365) function that recognizes different words in the same cell and changes them individually

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What im working with

[image]

I have a list of product names, but unfortunately they are written in uppercase I now want to make only the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase but I also want all words with 3 or less symbols to stay uppercase

im trying if functions but nothing is really working

i use the german excel version but i would be happy if someone has any idea on how to do it im trying different functions for hours but nothing is working

```
=IF(LENGTH(C6)<=3,UPPER(C6),UPPER(LEFT(C6,1))&LOWER(RIGHT(C6,LENGTH(C6)-1)))
```

but its a #NAME error excel does not recognize the first and the last bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hard! Let me explain:

1. I do believe there are German words in the mix that are below 4 characters in length that you should exclude. My German isn't great but there would probably be a huge deal of words below 4 characters;
2. There seems to be substrings that are 3+ characters in length but should probably stay uppercase, e.g. '550E/ER';
3. There seem to be quite a bunch of characters that could be used as delimiters to split the input into 'words'. It's hard to catch any of them without a full list;
4. Possible other reasons;

With the above in mind I think it's safe to say that we can **try** to accomplish something that you want as best as we can. Therefor I'd suggest

- To split on multiple characters;
- Exclude certain words from being uppercase when length < 3;
- Include certain words to be uppercase when length > 3 and digits are present;
- Assume 1st character could be made uppercase in any input;

For example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(v,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(v,{"-","/"," ","."},,1),y,TEXTSPLIT(v,x,,1),z,TEXTJOIN(y,,MAP(x,LAMBDA(w,IF(SUM(--(w={"zu","ein","für","aus"})),LOWER(w),IF((LEN(w)<4)+SUM(IFERROR(FIND(SEQUENCE(10,,0),w),)),UPPER(w),LOWER(w)))))),UPPER(LEFT(z))&MID(z,2,LEN(v)))))
```

You can see how difficult it is to capture each and every possibility;

- The minute you exclude a few words, another will pop-up (the 'x' between numbers for example. Which should stay upper/lower-case depending on the context it is found in);
- The second you include words containing digits, you notice that some should be excluded ('00SICHERUNGS....');
- If the 1st character would be a digit, the whole above solution would not change 1st alpha-char in upper;
- Maybe some characters shouldn't be used as delimiters based on context? Think about hypenated words;
- Possible other reasons.

Point is, this is not just hard, it's extremely hard if not **impossible** to do on the type of data you are currently working with! Even if one is proficient with writing a regular expression (chuck in all (non-available to Excel) tokens, quantifiers and methods if you like), I'd doubt all edge-case could be covered.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read through the formula and was able to kinda understand it after some time. 

However, I am currently experiencing an issue with my Excel version 2108 where it is not recognizing the first and last brackets and is giving me an error message stating "you do not want to write a formula?". 

Can you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: i  also swapped every "," with a ";" and this game me the #NAME! error 

so i swapped every english formula with the german equivalent and now it dosent recognize the formular as a formular anymore

Comment: i just found the Problem my Excel is Excel LTSC Standart 2021 
and for the "=Map" and the "=LAMBDA" Function i need Office 365

Thanks for the help i will mark his answer as correct and close it right here

Comment: Are you able to use excel for web? (Through Office.com). You may have access to these functions through there?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are dealing with any number of words in a cell you'll need to get crafty with this one. Thankfully there is `TEXTSPLIT()` and `TEXTJOIN()` that can make short work of splitting the text into words, where we can then test the length, change the capitalization, and then join them back together all in one formula:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(C6," "))<=3,UPPER(TEXTSPLIT(C6," ")),PROPER(TEXTSPLIT(C6," "))))
```

Also used `PROPER()` formula as well, which only capitalizes the first character of a word.